# Recommender matchbox

Tags: azure, recommendation-engine

I read about Matchbox Recommender, but I don't understand if and how the model can take into account my feedback incrementally. I mean, I can create my model and use it through a web service, but if I rate other items, my model updates itself real-time considering my new rates?

Regards

Andrea

Comment: Sorry, I am talking about Microsof Azure Matchbox Recommender:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/fa4aa69d-2f1c-4ba4-ad5f-90ea3a515b4c

Answer (score 0):

If your consideration is retraining your model with your new data, you can reference the following URL:
1.
https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Tutorial/No-code-Batch-Scoring-and-Retraining-1?r=legacy
2.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/retraining-and-updating-azure-machine-learning-models-with-azure-data-factory/